# Build a HREF from MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a link from mysql results:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<a class=post_link href=http://localhost:8888/search.php?loc=".$row['loc']."&lt=".$row['lt']."&lg=".$row['lg'].">".$row['loc'].": ".$row['lt'].", ".$row['lg']."</a><br>" ;
}
```

The problem is, when 'loc' row contains more than one word. Is it possible to detect when it has two or more words and insert '%' between them, or I need to use different technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PHP function `urlencode()`. This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL. More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<a class=post_link href=http://localhost:8888/search.php?loc=".urlencode($row['loc'])."&lt=".$row['lt']."&lg=".$row['lg'].">".$row['loc'].": ".$row['lt'].", ".$row['lg']."</a><br>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use ereg_replace, since urlencode (supposedly, no personal experience) sometimes acts a bit weird:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $loc = ereg_replace("[ \t\n\r]+", "%", $row['loc']);
    echo "<a class=post_link href=http://localhost:8888/search.php?loc=".$loc."&lt=".$row['lt']."&lg=".$row['lg'].">".$row['loc'].": ".$row['lt'].", ".$row['lg']."</a><br>" ;
}
```

This also replaces new line and tab characters.